# Ansible local_action example how does it work

Tags: ansible

How does the following Ansible play work:

```yaml
- name: Generate join command
    command: kubeadm token create --print-join-command
    register: join_command

  - name: Copy join command to local file
    local_action: copy content="{{ join_command.stdout_lines[0] }}" dest="./join-command"
```

So as I understand, local_action is the same as delegate_to
but, copy content= did not make any sense. Isn't the actual command like "cp" need to be specified?

Take this example:
`local_action: command ping -c 1 {{ inventory_hostname }}`

Can we use something like this:

`local_action: command cp content="{{ join_command.stdout_lines[0] }}" dest="./join-command"`

Answer (score 26, accepted):

> So as I understand, local_action is the same as delegate_to ...

`local_action` is similar to `delegate_to: localhost`, but because `local_action` requires you to change the syntax of tasks, it's better to always use `delegate_to`.  That is, while for a standard task, you might write:

```
- name: copy a file
  copy:
    src: myfile
    dest: /path/to/myfile
```

And for a delegated task, you would use exactly the same syntax with the addition of the `delegate_to` line:

```
- name: copy a file
  delegate_to: localhost
  copy:
    src: myfile
    dest: /path/to/myfile
```

When using `local_action` you have to change the syntax of the task:

```
- name: copy a file
  local_action:
    module: copy
    src: myfile
    dest: /path/to/myfile
```

> copy content= did not make any sense. Isn't the actual command like "cp" need to be specified?

No, `copy` is the name of an ansible module. You can see some examples of above, or just take a look at the [documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/copy_module.html).

> so looking at an example: local_action: command ping -c 1 {{ inventory_hostname }} Can we say:
>
> local_action: command cp content="{{ join_command.stdout_lines[0] }}" dest="./join-command"

You should use `delegate_to`, and you should write it like this:

```
- delegate_to: localhost
  copy:
    content: "{{ join_command.stdout_lines[0] }}"
    dest: ./join-command
```

Or if you actually want to run the `cp` command instead of the `copy` module, you would write something like:

```
- delegate_to: localhost
  command: cp some_file another_file
```

That is simply running the standard `cp` command, which knows nothing about `content=` or `dest=`.

Comment: delegate_to default is current host/localhost, so why use it for local actions?

Comment: You'll note that I'm not using `local_action`.

Comment: "it's better to always use delegate_to" that's a strong verdict, can you give a reference indicating that the two have no difference?

Comment: Using `local_action` requires changes to the syntax of your task that you can avoid using `delegate_to`.

Comment: The `delegate_to:` run the task as many times as we have hosts, right? How can you run the task only once?

Comment: There is a [`run_once`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/playbooks_keywords.html#term-run_once) directive that may do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Hard to say what's the path to *dest="./join-command"*. The full path works as expected.

For example:

```
dest="{{ playbook_dir }}/join-command"
```

Comment: I tried using your path dest: "{{ playbook_dir }}/join-command", but since it expects. the. file join-command in my local ( Mac ) 1. The file isn't there. 2. I get error:
TASK [copy] ********************************************************************
fatal: [k8s-master]: FAILED! => {"msg": "Failed to get information on remote file (/Users/syedahmed/KUBERNETES/VAG-K8S-ANSIBLE/kubernetes-setup/join-command): sudo: a password is required\n"}
So the password for sudo means sudo required for my local Mac Host.

Comment: You might want to either 1) point '*dest*' to where you can write, or 2) escalate privilege. See [Understanding Privilege Escalation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/become.html#understanding-privilege-escalation).

Comment: I am trying to implement https://kubernetes.io/blog/2019/03/15/kubernetes-setup-using-ansible-and-vagrant/ so I am guessing its the vagrant user trying to write "kubernetes-setup/join-command" file on the. host Mac. so I am guessing I have to "become" sudo on Mac from the. user vagrant?

Comment: Did you get it to work? I'm trying to implement the same setup and get the error "[k8s-master]: FAILED! => {"msg": "Failed to get information on remote file (./join-command): sudo: a password is required\n"}

Comment: @André: Solve the problem with sudo first(`sudo: a password is required`) and try again.

Comment: `become_user: root` seemed to solve it, the path worked as expected

Comment: @kamal If you are following instructions in that blog, there is something you might need to adjust: 

1) Add -K in vagrant file 
ansible.raw_arguments  = "-K"

2) Add become_user: root in ansible playbook file